# Safari ignoring css max-width media queries below a certain point

Tags: css, safari, media-queries

I'm working on optimizing a responsive site and Safari (both desktop and mobile) seems to be completely ignoring media queries below a certain point.  I have code like the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    /* Safari responds to css here */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    /* css here is ignored by Safari */
}
```

Firefox and Chrome both respond appropriately.  Does anyone have any ideas about what is going on?

You can see the site here: http://kgillingham.webfactional.com.  What should happen (and works on FF and Chrome) is that as the site becomes less than 640px the header font in the slider should become a smaller size.

**edit**: The site has now been updated to use javascript to add a class when the size is less than 640px.  That class always uses the smaller font size.  This means that it works as expected now, but I would much rather use CSS media queries than javascript so I would still like to see a solution.

Comment: So I was able to replicate this in Safari but I have no idea why this is happening.  It's as if it just starts ignoring media queries when it feels like it.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what it seems like to me, thanks for the confirmation that I'm not crazy!

Comment: Does Safari have some kind of retina display thing going on?

Comment: I don't think that's the case because it responds appropriately to the 767px query.

Comment: Can you provide a small fiddle ?

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  I created the fiddle and it worked as expected which took me back to my code since I now knew that safari could respond appropriately.  I found a missing squiggly brace on a line a ways above the css that wasn't being evaluated.  Apparently Safari can't handle this and wasn't evaluating any css after the missing brace, while other, browsers were able to handle this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a squiggly brace, so I had code like the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    /* lots of css */
    .some_selector { padding: 20px; /*<---- missing squiggly brace*/
    /* more css */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    /* lots more css */
}
```

Inserting the missing brace caused Safari to begin working.  Other browsers didn't choke on the error which is partially why it was so difficult to track down.

Thanks for the help everyone, I feel pretty silly now.

Comment: Then +1 for having found the error, and -1 for not having posted the code snippet needed for troubleshooting :D

Comment: I actually posted the website that was having the trouble so you could have looked at the CSS, so I did post the code.  The code I posted above is highly redacted, the actual css file is 100s of lines long so it would not have been practical to post the whole thing here.

Comment: Start using a linter with your code editor. :D I use SublimeLinter with Sublime Text 2, which runs CSSLint (and many other linters) as I type: has saved me from myself more times than I'd care to remember.

Comment: Don't feel silly — sometimes when you make a stupid mistake and solve it, you help another person who made the same silly mistake (me, in this case) solve their problem. Thanks!

Comment: had the same issue here... chrome didnt care about the missing "brace". but safari and android/iphone/ipod didnt like it at all..thanks!

Comment: Hundred years later safari still doesn't work .... but only without `-webkit-` for example: `@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {`  works with mozilla but does not works with safari, when you do `@media screen and (-webkit-min-width: 400px) {`  then works with both.

Answer (score 0):

@media rules are the same concept as normal css rules, the latest rule overwrites the first one. but if a rule is different it would not overrule it.

you could make a workaround by typing, this code would just interpreted by webkits

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    /* put webkit CSS here*/
}
```

Comment: I understand that and that is why I put the smaller width after the larger, so that it would override.  As I stated I am having no problem in Firefox and Chrome so I don't think this is an ordering issue, it seems to be particular to Safari.

Comment: Even on iPhones only the CSS from the first media query is used even though the 2nd media query should be used.  If you haven't already take a look at http://kgillingham.webfactional.com in Safari (if you have it) to see the problem in action.  I think it's weird that it works in Chrome since Chrome is also Webkit.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help!  It turns out there was an error in my css, I posted an answer of my own that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing a similar issue with media query the queries were working at wrong break points: [This thread](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/media-queries-not-working-with-safari/33209/7) has something that might help others coming here. To quote

**Try zooming to a zoom in/out to 0 ie. normal resolution. Press `Command + 0`**

> Just a thought: could you have your font sizes bumped up in Safari? Try pressing Command 0 to make sure it’s reset to the default font size.
>
> No but what you said made me figure it out!!! Thank you both for helping me work through this. The problem is, I was testing the media query not by resizing the window, but by zooming in on the page.
>
> So, my question isn’t what I thought it was. Should I re-post this as a new question? In FF and Chrome, the media query in the above code kicks in when I zoom in on the web page, but in Safari, it doesn’t. Is there anything I can do to make Safari act more like FF and Chrome here?