# @media query doesn't work on IPhone

Tags: css, iphone, media-queries, media

My `media query` works on Android in all browsers but not on IPhone.
 I have IPhone 6s Plus and when I opened my website, it crashed the page. On other IPhones it's just css in mess. What's the problem?

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px)  and  (orientation : portrait) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use :

```
@media (max-width:768px) {

}
```

In my opinion, the other parameters are irrelevant, they just lead you to messy stylesheets.

But keep in mind that a better approach may be to **set breakpoints based on content and layout.**

I advise you to read this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564752/common-breakpoints-for-media-queries-on-a-responsive-site)

Comment: thanks for your answer but it didn't help me :( Do you know why @media could crash all browsers on IPhone?

Comment: Never had this issue.. Did you read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301910/iphone-is-ignoring-css-media-queries-viewport-tag-present-working-in-desktop)