# Media Queries not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, safari, media

My media queries are working in Firefox and Chrome but not Safari.

```
@media screen (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1),
    and (min-device-width: 1000px), 
    and (max-device-width: 1600px),
    and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { }
```

They were working absolutely fine in safari until I added in some extra code to support Firefox.

I also have

> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

in my HTML so it's not this.

Please help!!

Comment: maybe there shouldn't be commas in front of the ands?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976751/safari-ignoring-css-max-width-media-queries-below-a-certain-point Someone also had some problems with Safari-Media-Queries. Did you already check your CSS-Code of missing braces anywhere? Safari seems to be slightly fussy.

Comment: Hi Dustin, yes I've already checked for missing braces and they're all in there!

Comment: @Pavlin the commas don't make a difference, Safari still isn't picking up the query

Comment: and you're trying this on a screen with 192dpi?

Comment: yeah, I am. It was all working fine yesterday

Comment: can you reproduce that in a fiddle?

Comment: pixel-ratio can't be 1 while resolution is 192dpi.

Answer (score 3):

Your operation:

```
@media screen (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1),
and (min-device-width: 1000px), 
and (max-device-width: 1600px),
and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { }
```

reads:

```
or and (min-device-width: 1000px)
or and (max-device-width: 1600px)
or and and (min-resolution: 192dpi)
```

[By documentation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

> > comma-separated lists
>
> Comma-separated lists behave like the logical operator `or` when used in media queries. When using a comma-separated list of media queries, if any of the media queries returns true, the styles or style sheets get applied. Each media query in a comma-separated list is treated as an individual query, and any operator applied to one media query does not affect the others. This means the comma-separated media queries can target different media features, types, and states.

Either check that this is the intended behavior, or separate the logical operations `and` and `or` from each other...
Firefox/Chrome have better implementations on rules, and can thus "fix" common logical fallacies in them.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it, I have separated the media query into two so that it is

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1),
and (min-device-width: 1000px), 
and (max-device-width: 1600px) { }
```

and then

```
@media screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { }
```

this has solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
// For safari version 15.4 only 

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1),
and (min-device-width: 1000px), 
and (max-device-width: 1600px) { 

  .search-field .top-search .form-group input[type='search'] {
     height: 44px !important;    
    }
    .dropdown{ padding: 2px 20px; }
    .nice-select{height: 44px;}
}


@media screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
  body{line-height: 26px!important;}
 .search-field .top-search .form-group input[type='search'] {
     height: 44px !important;
  }
  .dropdown{ padding: 2px 20px; }
  .nice-select{height: 44px;}   

}
```

For Example :
[image: Media Queries not working in Safari]

Answer (score -1):

@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm)
{ @supports (-webkit-appearance:none) and (stroke-color:transparent) {

//add ur media queries.
//Queries inside this will work only for safari

}