# html media query not working in iphone devices

Tags: html, css, iphone, media-queries, footer

i have a website, in the website in a page [enter link description here](http://molugu.com/yantraev/about-company/) in mobile view the footer has gone up, so i did the following code:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #ltx-widgets-footer {
    margin-top: 128% !important
  }
}
```

this is working fine in all android phones, but in iphones its not, can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, thanks in advance

Comment: try it - `@media (max-width: 600px) { ... }`

Comment: @s.kuznetsov tried bro, still no change

Comment: The media query displayed in the browser developer inspector?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov i didnt get you bro?

Comment: Also try it, pls - `@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { ... }`, and look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411696/media-queries-not-working-in-safari

Comment: @s.kuznetsov tried bro, no change

Comment: How exactly does it not work on iphone? Does the block not change its position?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov its actually a footer, it went in the middle of the content, so i used media query and it worked in all mobile devices except iphone devices, it in the same old position