# css min related media queries not working in safari browser

Tags: html, css, vue.js, media-queries

I am trying to add a media query which contains `min`. It's not working in safari browser.

```
@media (min-height: 568px) and (max-height: 568px) and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 320px) {
  #exe {
    width: 100px !important;
  }
}
```

Above code is working fine in chrome browser. But no idea why it's not executing in safari mobile mode.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Already added the above meta tag as well. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411696/media-queries-not-working-in-safari

Comment: There it was related to a comma issue right? In my case no commas @nagendranag

Comment: Could you put up a little snippet that we can run to see the problem. This should help you do this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You have a spurious space after max-

Comment: updated, still not works @AHaworth