# Media Queries in CSS file not working on Safari

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

My responsive design is working in every browser but Safari. Here is a screenshot of the code in the main file and in the CSS file. Is there something I have missed? Why isn't this working?

I should add that the media query works perfectly in the HTML file in a  tag but will not work in a seperate CSS file.

Thank you in advance

```css
/* Nav Bar Dynamic */
@media screen and (max-width: 1999px) {
    /* code here */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
    /* code here */
}
/* End NavBar dynamic */
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Styles/newStyle.css"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="/Images/manLogo.png">
    <script src="/NewSite/JavaScript/exploreScript.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

Comment: I should clarify the media query works on safari if it is in a <style> tag in the file, but will not work in a seperate CSS file!

Comment: Hi! please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411696/media-queries-not-working-in-safari

Comment: Make sure the other file is a CSS file or if you are adding media in other files you have to add a media query under the style

Comment: What else is in that CSS file, are the media queries towards the end of it and is the file definitely loading?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the file is definitely loading as the styles from the file work throughout the website, I have placed the media queries at the bottom of the file and it is still working on everything but Safari :(

Comment: Please use Webkit for Some of the queries which is help to work in Safari