# Media Queries not working in safari, but working in chrome

Tags: html, css, safari, media-queries, mobile-safari

Currently creating a single-page website. My Media Queries are not working in iOS safari but they do work in my desktop Chrome emulator for mobile devices. removing the js script doesn't change anything either so i do not think it is js related. Here is the URL http://www.quincegr.com/music-militia/

here is the expected result:
[image: the responsive version of the website in chrome device emulator]

this is the actual result on iOS:
[image: the iOS safari result]

I've set my meta tag to a responsive format but it doesn't change to the device width

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name='viewport' content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height"/>
    <title>MME</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/css/glide.core.min.css">
</head>
```

this is the way that the media queries are written, which the CSS code inside does not recognise:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    section {
        
        min-height: 80vh;
        padding: 5rem;
    }
```

I have the source code of the website here https://github.com/spikethea/music-militia-ent/tree/master
Any suggestions, help would be extremely appreciated, thank you

Comment: Have you tried removing the `only` from the media query?

Comment: Hey, yeah ive just tried that it, doesn't make any difference sadly, but thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411696/media-queries-not-working-in-safari Please have a look at this and try those `min-device-width`, `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` or `min-resolution`.