# Safari ignoring css media queries

Tags: safari, media-queries

[novantiqua.net/very-new/e62.html](http://novantiqua.net/very-new/e62.html)

I want to hide some images and texts of certain popups if the screen height is too small, but it's not working on Macbook Air (with Safari as Web Browser). I don't know why.
[Safari ignoring css max-width media queries below a certain point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976751/safari-ignoring-css-max-width-media-queries-below-a-certain-point) didn't help me.

css:

```
@media screen and ( max-height: 800px ){
.nasconditi-se-schermo-piccolo {display:none;}
 h1{font-size:14px;}
}
```

html:

```
<h1>2 CD | Tuscania</h1>
    <h2 class="nasconditi-se-schermo-piccolo">NA17</h2>
    <img 
    src="cd-grafiche-400px/NA17-tuscania.jpg" 
    width="200" class="nasconditi-se-schermo-piccolo">
<p>
<b>Prima registrazione mondiale</b> dei Quartetti op.21 di Cambini.
<br>Libretto con un articolo storiografico sulla conquista dei diritti civili in Corsica e in Toscana nella seconda metá del Settecento.
<br>Cambini | 6 Quatuors Concertant op.21
<br>Boccherini | Duo per viola e violoncello
<br>
<br><b>Ensemble Alraune</b></p>
```

[screenshot from a not working "display:none" rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p4xo.png)